# JSON Serializer returning n^2 the number of expected entries

Tags: entity-framework, serialization, asp.net-web-api, json.net, entity-framework-core

I have an API which is producing some interesting results. When debugging, the everything is as expected till serialization.

The *ScheduleEvent* entity has a foreign key to the *Project* entity. I'm trying to return all ScheduleEvents which match a given *id*.

When I run the below, it returns the correct result, but if it should return 10 entries, it returns 10^2 (correct result 10 times over).

```
return Ok(await _context.ScheduleEvent.Include(m => m.Project)
                .Where(x => x.Project.ProjectName == id).ToListAsync());
```

Originally the command below resulted in the self referencing loop detected error. I added the below which resolves the error.

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    //options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = 
    //              Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Include;

    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = 
                  Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});
```

If I run the below, it outputs as expected.

```
return Ok(await _context.Project.Include(p => p.ScheduleEvents)
               .Where(x => x.ProjectName == id).ToListAsync());
```

Code for the models:

**Project**

```
public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }

    ...

    public ICollection<ScheduleEvent> ScheduleEvents { get; set; } = null;
}
```

**ScheduleEvent**

```
public class ScheduleEvent
{
    [Key]
    [JsonProperty("ScheduleEventId")]
    public int ScheduleEventId { get; set; }

    ...

    [Display(Name = "Project")]
    [JsonProperty("Project")]
    [ForeignKey("ProjectForeignKey")]
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; } = null;
}
```

Comment: You may need to set `ProxyCreationEnabled = false`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983428/json-net-serialize-entity-framework-object-circular-reference-error and http://johnnycode.com/2012/04/10/serializing-circular-references-with-json-net-and-entity-framework/

Comment: can you show the` code` of the mode's classes ?