# Web Api + Entity Framework Not properly loading data

Tags: c#, rest, entity-framework-4.1, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I've built a small service using the ASP.NET Web Api. My domain classes looks like this:

```
 public class Drink : IEntity
{
    public Drink()
    {
        Ingridients = new List<Ingredient>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Ingredient> Ingridients { get; set; }
    public string Approach { get; set; }
}

public class Ingredient : IEntity
{
    public Ingredient()
    {
        Drinks = new List<Drink>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Drink> Drinks { get; set; }
}
```

My Repository Looks like this:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAll(){return _dbSet;}
```

And my controller looks like this:

```
    public IEnumerable<Drink> GetAllDrinks()
    {
        return _unitOfWork.Drinks.GetAll();
    }
```

When I make I request using fiddler the JSON result is the following:

```
{"Id":15,"Name":"Russian Energy","Ingridients":[],"Approach":"Mix Vodka with Redbull"}
```

As you can see the Ingridents array is empty. Why is that?

Comment: I added the json.net tag because this question is really, "why doesn't json.net serialize my EF graph correctly."  Web-api is incidental to the problem.

Comment: Have a look at this question on SO .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588143/ef-4-1-code-first-json-circular-reference-serialization-error

Comment: Also have a look at this blog that might be helpful: http://blog.davebouwman.com/2011/12/08/handling-circular-references-asp-net-mvc-json-serialization/

Comment: Looks interesting, Rajesh. I'll have a cloer look at it ASAP

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use *eager loading* with `Include`:

Extend your `GetAll` method to allow eager loading:

```
//...
using System.Data.Entity;
//...

public IEnumerable<T> GetAll(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = _dbSet;
    if (includes != null)
    {
        foreach (var include in includes)
            query = query.Include(include);
    }
    return query;
}
```

Then use it in your controller like so:

```
public IEnumerable<Drink> GetAllDrinks()
{
    return _unitOfWork.Drinks.GetAll(d => d.Ingredients);
}
```

Comment: Now I get a different error..like so <Error> <Message>An error has occurred.</Message> <ExceptionMessage> The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'. </ExceptionMessage> <ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType> <StackTrace/> <InnerException> <Message>An error has occurred.</Message> <ExceptionMessage> Object graph for type 'Gudo.Core.Model.Ingredient' contains cycles and cannot be serialized if reference tracking is disabled. </ExceptionMessage>

Comment: This error occurs after I applied the changes that Slauma suggested

Comment: @IAmSharp: Google for the error or ask a new question. There plenty of references about this problem over the Internet. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/658056/270591 or (for JSON.NET) http://johnnycode.com/2012/04/10/serializing-circular-references-with-json-net-and-entity-framework/ The error has nothing to do with your original problem that the ingredients are not loaded.

Comment: Ok..I'll add a new question

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Entity Framework Code First?

If so, you have to mark the navigation properties as `virtual`:

```
public class Drink : IEntity
{
    public Drink()
    {
        Ingridients = new List<Ingredient>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingridients { get; set; }
    public string Approach { get; set; }
}

public class Ingredient : IEntity
{
    public Ingredient()
    {
        Drinks = new List<Drink>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Drink> Drinks { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using CF. Marking the nav properties as virtual didn't help. I'm still getting the empty array.